# Magento cpu usage issues

Tags: magento-1.7, performance

I have magento installed on host gator everything was working fine.But suddenly they said my magento CPU usage  is very high so they are suspending my account and recommended to me either buy dedicated server or resolve the magento cpu usage  issue. Can any body tell me how to find out which part of my magento web site is taking so much cpu usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's **the Magento part** :)

Sincerely, though, Magento **is not meant** to be hosted on a **shared**-resource server and there is no magic bullet that will fix these 'issues'. However, I have had tremendous luck hosting very small shops at Amazon Web Services' EC2. At the time of this writing, their Spot instances run at about $115/year. That's a virtualized, dedicated environment.

Perhaps **you're not devops** and you don't want to manage the infrastructure/environment at all. I would check this list out of hosting partners with Magento and contact one of them:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/partners/hosting

Comment: Is it really problem of magento or they are just trying to sell their dedicated server to me bcs i am using the same magento configuration for other we site and they are workign fine. I am using Magento Web Hosting  http://www.hostgator.com/apps/magento-hosting.shtml.

Comment: Magento's notorious for beating up on shared hosting. Shared hosting expects all the players to play fair. Magento walks in with a club and takes what it wants or crashes the server doing it.

Comment: This is not really a Magento issue. However I would word Phils (otherwise completely true) statement a bit differently -- virtual hostings are not meant to be used for CPU intense software. Magento is CPU intense. In other words (I quote): "We're gonna need a bigger boat."